# Defining monad from scratch in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

After studying about monads in Haskell — a subject that is very compelling for everything that implies — I wonder if I could define a monad on my own without using the already defined typeclasses.

Instead of making `Monad` an instance of `Functor`, I just want to define a monad per se, with it's own `fmap` function (Also I wanted to change some function names such as `return` and call it `unit`).

A monad may be defined by the bind operator `(>>=)` and the function `return`, but it also may be defined in terms of `return` and `join` since this last function it can be expressed in terms of the bind operator: `join m = m >>= id`. So a monad could be (technically) defined in terms of `return` and `join` and nothing else. The function `fmap` is required (and the base of existence of a `Functor` in Haskell), but also could be defined in terms of `return`, for it may be defined also (I think) as follows: `fmap f m = m >>= return . f` *(before edit it was written, `fmap f m = return . f`; it was obviously a typo)*.

Yet I know this wouldn't be as efficient as using the predefined `Monad` typeclass, it's just to understand better the Haskell language.

How can I accomplish that? This is a depiction of this concept out of my head, right now, so it's not useful code:

```hs
-- Just a sketch
infixr 9 ∘
(∘) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(∘) g f x = g (f x)
--(f ∘ g) x = f (g x)

-- My own 'fmap'
--mapper id  =  id
--mapper (f ∘ g) = mapper f ∘ mapper g


-- My monad
class MyMonadBase (m :: * -> *) where
    unit :: a -> m a   --return

    join :: m (m a) -> m a
    join = (>>= id)

    mapper f m = m >>= unit ∘ f


--Testing:
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance MyMonadBase Tree where
    unit = Leaf
    join (Leaf x) = x
    join (Branch l r)  = Branch (join l) (join r)
```

Am I in the right track (conceptually)?

Comment: `fmap f = return . f` – this doesn't work. The type of `return . f` is `a -> m b`, not `m a -> m b`. Neither does `mapper` work: you can't pattern-match on `id` or `∘` unless you define them as _data constructors_. — Anyway... I don't quite see what you're trying to achieve here. A monad is, fundamentally, first of all a functor. Even if it's technically possible to omit that requirement, doesn't mean it makes sense to do that. Haskell98 did, and it was quickly realised that this wasn't a good idea.

Comment: `(g <$>) = (return . g =<<)`, i.e. `return` is not enough, you also need bind for this. `(k =<<) = join . (k <$>)`, so you must have `(<$>)` (i.e. `fmap`) with the `join`. cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it wasn't that difficult. I had the misconception that implementing a own monad type will be extremely complex, but it's just applying the definition.

```
-- My monad
class MyMonad m where
    unit :: a -> m a
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
    mapf :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b


--Testing MyMonad
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

instance MyMonad Tree where
    unit = Leaf
    join (Leaf x) = x
    join (Branch l r) = Branch (join l) (join r)
    mapf f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
    mapf f (Branch l r) = Branch (mapf f l) (mapf f r)

t = Branch (Branch (Leaf 1) (Leaf 3)) (Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 4))


-- My bind (just for completeness, not that I need it for this example)
(>>>) :: MyMonad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
xs >>> f = join (mapf f xs)


-- Testing my bind
extr :: Integer -> Tree Integer
extr x = Branch (Leaf (x^2)) (Leaf (2^x))

t >>> extr
--Branch (Branch (Branch (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Branch (Leaf 9) (Leaf 8))) 
--       (Branch (Branch (Leaf 4) (Leaf 4)) (Branch (Leaf 16) (Leaf 16)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Some small corrections:

> A monad may be defined by the bind operator `(>>=)` and the function `return`, but it also may be defined in terms of `return` and `join` since this last function it can be expressed in terms of the bind operator: `join m = m >>= id`.

The conclusion ("[a monad] also may be defined in terms of `return` and `join`") is correct, but the premise ("since [`join`] can be expressed in terms of the bind operator") does not imply it. Instead you must show that the operator you are omitting -- the bind operator -- may be defined in terms of the things you have -- `return` and `join`. Once you try to do this, you see why it is so critical that a monad also be a functor:

```
m >>= f = join (fmap f m)
```

> The function `fmap` is required (and the base of existence of a `Functor` in Haskell), but also could be defined in terms of `return`, for it may be defined also (I think) as follows: `fmap f m = return . f`

That's not quite a correct definition of `fmap` -- and you should be suspicious indeed, since the right hand side doesn't mention `m`! A correct version would be:

```
fmap f m = m >>= return . f
```

But now this is a circular definition, since above we planned on defining `(>>=)` in terms of `fmap`. So if you want to make `return` and `join` the basic operations of `Monad`, you really do need to implement `fmap` separately.

> I know this wouldn't be as efficient as using the predefined `Monad` typeclass

I don't see any reason to believe this a priori. The reason `(>>=)` is chosen over `join` is not because it is more efficient, but because it is such a natural operation when using monads in programming.

As for your actual code, I think it looks fine with two caveats:

1. I strongly suspect your definition of `mapper` does not do what you think it does. In the line `mapper id = id`, the pattern `id` on the left hand side matches all incoming values, and the variable `id` on the right hand side returns them unchanged. The line `mapper (f ∘ g) = mapper f ∘ mapper g` is simply not valid Haskell. (Perhaps these two lines were intended to be documentation of the laws required of `mapper` rather than actual code?)
2. It is strange to offer default implementations of `join` and `mapper` in terms of `(>>=)` -- both for the reasons above (all three are fundamental and must be defined) and because `(>>=)` is not a class operation, hence can't be defined by the user in a meaningful way.

Comment: `join . fmap f` *will* be slower than `(f =<<)` for many functors.