# Difference in capability between fmap and bind?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor

I'm new to functional programming (coming from javascript), and I'm having a hard time telling the difference between the two, which is also messing with my understand of functors vs. monads.

Functor:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Monad (simplified):

```
class Monad m where
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

- `fmap` takes a function and a functor, and returns a functor.
- `>>=` takes a function and a monad, and returns a monad.

The difference between the two is in the function parameter:

- `fmap` - `(a -> b)`
- `>>=` - `(a -> m b)`

`>>=` takes a function parameter that returns a monad. I know that this is significant, but I'm having difficulty seeing how this one slight thing makes monads much more powerful than functors. Can someone explain?

Comment: this is easier seen with the flipped version of `(>>=)`, [`(=<<)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605). With `(g <$>) :: f a -> f b`, the function `g :: a -> b` has no influence on the `f` "wrapping" -- doesn't change it. With `(k =<<) :: m a -> m b`, the function `k :: a -> m b` itself *creates* the new `m` "wrapping", so it can change.

Comment: @WillNess I can "understand" this, but I can't see it. I think the real problem I have is that I can't see what `>>=` can do that `fmap` can't do. In my head they're equivalent because I haven't seen an example, which shows that fmap is inadequate.

Comment: going with lists, try to filter out some elements from a list, using `map`. you can't. but with `concatMap`, you can: `map (\x->x+1) [1,2,3]` vs `concatMap (\x-> [x,x+1|even x]) [1,2,3])`.

Comment: @WillNess okay I see! I always thought a `filter` operation was just a sugary variant of `map`, but just now I've realized that's not even possible.

Comment: we can code *almost*-filter with `map (\x -> [x|even x]) [1,2,3]` but  it produces `[[],[2],[]]` and another level of interpretation done by `concat` is then needed to make it really a `filter`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, `(<$>)` is an alias for `fmap`, and `(=<<)` is the same as `(>>=)` with the arguments swapped:

```
(<$>) :: (x ->   y) -> b x -> b y
(=<<) :: (x -> b y) -> b x -> b y
```

The difference is now fairly clear: with the bind function, we apply a function that returns a `b y` rather than a `y`. So what difference does that make?

Consider this small example:

```
foo <$> Just 3
```

Notice that `(<$>)` will apply `foo` to `3`, and put the result back into a `Just`. In other words, the result of this computation *cannot* be `Nothing`. On the contrary:

```
bar =<< Just 3
```

This computation *can* return `Nothing`. (For example, `bar x = Nothing` will do it.)

We can do a similar thing with the list monad:

```
foo <$> [Red, Yellow, Blue]   -- Result is guaranteed to be a 3-element list.
bar =<< [Red, Yellow, Blue]   -- Result can be ANY size.
```

In short, with `(<$>)` (i.e., `fmap`), the "structure" of the result is always identical to the input. But with `(=<<)` (i.e., `(>>=)`), the structure of the result can change. This allows conditional execution, reacting to input, and a whole bunch of other things.

Comment: just for completeness, Applicative can return `Nothing` too: `Nothing <*> Just 3`. The difference is, the "piping" (i.e. computational structure) is *fixed* when the computation is composed, *before* it *"runs"*. But with Monads the piping can change depending on the values produced *while* it "runs". (in case of IO, `3` presumably is received e.g. as user's input). -- The *list* example is esp. good here: `(foo <$>)` keeps the structure (list's length); `([baz, quux] <*>)` will change the structure *predictably* (create length-6 list); with Monad all bets are off.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer is that if you can turn `m (m a)` into `m a` in a way which makes sense then it's a Monad. This is possible for all Monads but not necessarily for Functors.

I think the most confusing thing is that all of the common examples of Functors (e.g. `List`, `Maybe`, `IO`) are also Monads. We need an example of something that is a Functor but not a Monad.

I'll use an example from a hypothetical calendar program. The following code defines an `Event`  Functor which stores some data that goes with the event and the time that it occurs.

```
import Data.Time.LocalTime

data Event a = MkEvent LocalTime a

instance Functor Event where
    fmap f (MkEvent time a) = MkEvent time (f a)
```

The `Event` object stores the time that the event occurs and some extra data that can be changed using `fmap`. Now lets try and make it a Monad:

```
instance Monad Event where
    (>>=) (MkEvent timeA a) f = let (MkEvent timeB b) = f a in
                                MkEvent <notSureWhatToPutHere> b
```

We find that we can't because you will end up with two `LocalTime` objects. `timeA` from the given `Event` and `timeB` from the `Event` given by the result of `f a`. Our `Event` type is defined as having only one `LocalTime` (`time`) that it occurs at and so making it a Monad isn't possible without turning two `LocalTime`s into one. (There may be some case where doing so might make sense and so you could turn this into a monad if you really wanted to).

Comment: One example of a classic/common functor that's not a monad is `newtype Const a b = Const a`.

Comment: `pure x >>= f` is required by a monad law to be `f x`, but `pure :: b -> Const a b` cannot possibly use its argument.

Comment: @dfeuer This seams [too simple to be simple](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple). Also I can't find a way to write a Functor instance other than `fmap f (Const x) = Const x`

Comment: @HEGX64: right. but for `Functor` this is no problem – in fact, it immediately guarantees the functor law `fmap id ≡ id`.

Comment: A less simple example: in FRP frameworks, events and signals tend to be functors, but not monads. This turns out to be important for efficient implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Assume for a moment that `IO` were just a `Functor`, and not a `Monad`. How could we sequence two actions? Say, like `getChar :: IO Char` and `putChar :: Char -> IO ()`.

We could try mapping over `getChar` (an action that, when executed, reads a `Char` from stdin) using `putChar`.

```
fmap putChar getChar :: IO (IO ())
```

Now we have a program that, when executed, reads a `Char` from stdin and produces a program that, when executed, writes the `Char` to stdout. But what we actually want is a program that, when executed, reads a `Char` from stdin and writes the `Char` to stdout. So we need a "flattening" (in the `IO` case, "sequencing") function with type:

```
join :: IO (IO ()) -> IO ()
```

`Functor` by itself does not provide this function. But it is a function of `Monad`, where it has the more general type:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

What does all of this have to do with `>>=`? As it happens, monadic bind is just a combination of `fmap` and `join`:

```
:t \m f -> join (fmap f m)
(Monad m) => m a1 -> (a1 -> m a) -> m a
```

Another way of seeing the difference is that `fmap` never changes the overall structure of the mapped value, but `join` (and therefore `>>=` as well) can do that.

In terms of `IO` actions, `fmap` will *never* cause addicional reads/writes or other effects. But `join` sequences the read/writes of the inner action after those of the outer action.