# Why does haskell's bind function take a function from non-monadic to monadic

Tags: haskell, monads

I have some questions about the definition of the binding function `(>>=)` in Haskell.

Because Haskell is a pure language, so we can use Monad to handle operations with side effects. I think this strategy is somewhat like putting all actions may cause side effects to another world, and we can control them from our "pure" haskell world though `do` or `>>=`.

So when I look at definition of `>>=` function

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

it takes a `(a -> m b)` function, so result `m a` of the former action can be "unpack" to a non-monadic `a` in `>>=`. Then the function `(a -> m b)` takes `a` as its input and return another monadic `m b` as its result. By the binding function I can operate on monadic without bringing any side effects into pure haskell codes.

My question is why we use a `(a -> m b)` function? In my opinion, a `m a -> m b` function can also do this. Is there any reason, or just because it is designed like this?

**EDIT**

From comments I understand it's hard to extract `a` from `m a`. However, I think I can consider a monadic `m a` as a `a` with side effect.

Is it possible to assume function `m a -> m b` acts similar with `a -> b`, so we can define `m a -> m b` like defining `a -> b`?

Comment: An `m a -> m b` function can't do that because there's no general way to extract an `a` from an `m a`, `IO` being the most common example.

Comment: Well usually you cannot get a "value" out of a monad. The state of an I/O monad is for instance your entire system (and the state of the entire file system, the servers on the internet, hardware) at that moment (well virtually of course).

Comment: As addition, you can think about `a -> m b` as a callback. When computations will be run it can be called by "interpretator".

Comment: If it were `m a -> m b`, then we could always let `x >>= f = f x` for any `m`. This would be non interesting: it would not implement the "temporary unboxing" that `>>=` is about, since `f` would not be passed the "unboxed value".

Comment: To expand the example by Lee: consider `readLn >>= \n -> print (n+10 :: Int)` in the IO monad. This works because `n::Int`, if it were `n :: IO Int` we couldn't add 10 (nor print the result).

Comment: @Lee I think if a value has type `m a`, it means this value is somewhat "unsafe" because it may cause side effects, apart from this, `m a` is just like `a`, so why can't we assume function `m a -> m b` acts similar with `a -> b`, so we can define `m a -> m b` like defining `a -> b`?

Comment: OK try defining a function of type `IO Int -> IO String` without using `>>=`.

Comment: @calvin - The additional power that `Monad` has over `Applicative` is the ability to inspect the inner value `a` to choose the resulting value `m b`. If `(>>=)` took a function `m a -> m b` then you would need a function `m a -> a` to be able to inspect an `a` to decide on which value `m b` to return. However monads do not support such a function. Since monads are functors they already support lifting `a -> b` to `m a -> m b` with `fmap`.

Comment: @Lee *If `(>>=)` took a function `m a -> m b`* then it would be called `(.)`.

Comment: @n.m. I don't think that is a useful or interesting challenge. `fmap show` is one reasonable example. It's quite easy to do using just Functor. The exciting thing about the Monad interface is that it lets us do *more* than that, by "changing" the IO wrapping our value.

Comment: @amalloy hmmm I'm still living in the pre-AMP universe apparently.

Comment: @amalloy right; so the question becomes, "can we satisfy ourselves with just `fmap`?" And the answer is of course "no": we'd have to have a _primitive_ `IO a` already defined for us, describing  any crazy computation that comes into our minds, to `fmap f` inside it (inside that `IO a` value, describing that crazy computation). (I'm paraphrasing here what you've said).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in capability between fmap and bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387237/difference-in-capability-between-fmap-and-bind)

Comment: @n.m. you meant not `(.)`, but `flip ($)` of course (and [`=<<` would become `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605)).

Comment: @WillNess yeah, sure, my mistake.

Comment: @n.m. not a mistake, just a minor detail. It *is* about the composition: [`((g <=< f) =<<)  =  (g =<<) . (f =<<)  =  join . (g <$>) . join . (f <$>)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234632/monads-with-join-instead-of-bind/11249714#11249714), and these "promoted" functions do plainly compose.

Comment: @calvin About "`m a` is just like `a`" -- no way! Consider `m = []`, the list monad. Is a list of integers the same as an integer? If `m = Maybe`, is an optional integer (which might not be there) the same as an integer? If `m = (-> ) String`, is a function from strings to integers the same as an integer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*edit2:* OK, here's what I should've said from the start:

### Monads are EDSLs,

*E* as in *embedded* domain-specific languages. *Embedded* means that the language's statements are plain values in *our* language, Haskell.

Let's try to have us an *IO*-language. Imagine we have `print1 :: IO ()` primitive, describing an action of printing an integer `1` at the prompt. Imagine we also have `print2 :: IO ()`. Both are plain Haskell values. In Haskell, we speak of these actions. This *IO*-language still needs to be interpreted / acted upon by some part of the run-time system *later*, at "run"-time. Having *two* languages, we have two worlds, two timelines.

We could write `do { print1 ; print2 }` to describe compound actions. But we can't create a new primitive for printing `3` at the prompt, as it is *outside* our *pure* Haskell world. What we have here is an EDSL, but evidently not a very powerful one. We must have an infinite supply of primitives here; *not* a winning proposition.  And it is not even a Functor, as we can't modify these values.

Now, what if we could? We'd then be able to tell `do { print1 ; print2 ; fmap (1+) print2 }`, to print out `3` as well. Now it's a Functor. More powerful, still not flexible enough.

We get flexibility with primitives for *constructing* these action descriptors (like `print1`). It is e.g. `print :: Show a => a -> IO a`. We can now talk about more versatile actions, like `do { print 42; getLine ; putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ "... you!") }`.

But now we see the need to refer to the *"results"* of previous actions. We want to be able to write `do { print 42; s <- getLine ; putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ s ++ "!") }`. We want to create (in Haskell world) new action descriptions (Haskell values describing actions in *IO*-world) based on  results (in Haskell world) of previous *IO*-actions that these *IO*-actions *will* produce, *when* they are run, *when* the *IO*-language is interpreted (the actions it describes been carried out in *IO*-world).

This means the ability to create those *IO*-language statements from Haskell values, like with `print :: a -> IO a`. And that is exactly the type you're asking about, and it *is* what makes this EDSL a *Monad*.

---

Imagine we have an IO primitive (`a_primitive :: IO Int -> IO ()`) which prints any positive integer as is, and prints `"---"` on a separate line before printing any non-positive integer. Then we could write `a_primitive (return 1)`, as you suggest.

But IO is closed; it is impure; we can't write new IO primitives in Haskell, and there can't be a primitive already defined for every new idea that might come into our minds. So we write `(\x -> if x > 0 then print x else do { putStrln "---"; print x })` instead, and that lambda expression's type is `Int -> IO ()` (more or less).

If the argument `x` in the above lambda-expression were of type `IO Int` the expression `x > 0` would be mistyped. There is no way to get that `a` out of `IO a`  without the use of the standard `>>=` operator (or its equivalent).

see also:

- [How Monads are considered Pure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438091/how-monads-are-considered-pure/39647091#39647091)
- [Difference between Monad and Applicative in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342184/difference-between-monad-and-applicative-in-haskell)
- [Is monad bind (>>=) operator closer to function composition (chaining) or function application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545818/is-monad-bind-operator-closer-to-function-composition-chaining-or-functi/34561605#34561605)
- [Monads with Join() instead of Bind()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234632/monads-with-join-instead-of-bind/11249714#11249714)
- [How to handle side effect with Applicative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467803/how-to-handle-side-effect-with-applicative/24467994#24467994)

And, this [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41310465/2):

> "Someone at some point noticed, "oh, in order to get impure effects
>   from pure code I need to do metaprogramming, which means one of my
>   types needs to be *'programs which compute an X'*. I want to take a
>   *'program that computes an X'* and a function which takes an X and
>   produces the next program, a *'program that computes a Y'*, and somehow
>   glue them together into a *'program which computes a Y'* " (which is the
>   `bind` operation). The IO monad was born."

---

*edit:* These are the four types of *generalized* function application:

```
( $ ) ::                     (a ->   b) ->   a ->   b     -- plain
(<$>) :: Functor f     =>    (a ->   b) -> f a -> f b     -- functorial
(<*>) :: Applicative f =>  f (a ->   b) -> f a -> f b     -- applicative
(=<<) :: Monad f       =>    (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b     -- monadic
```

And here are the corresponding type derivation rules, with the flipped arguments order for clarity,

```
 a                f a                f  a                f a
 a -> b             a -> b           f (a -> b)            a -> f b
 ------           --------           ----------          ----------
      b           f      b           f       b           f        b

 no `f`s          one `f`            two `f`s,           two `f`s: 
                                     both known          one known,
                                                         one constructed
```

Why? They just are. Your question is really, *why do we need Monads? Why Functors or Applicative Functors aren't enough?* And this was surely already asked and answered many times (e.g., the 2nd link in the list just above). For one, as I tried to show above, monads let us code new computations *in Haskell*.