# Pure maps in a monad

Tags: haskell, monads

Suppose I have two functions

```
f :: Monad m => a -> m a
g :: a -> a
```

that I want to consecutively apply to some element like so:

```
(return x) >>= f >>= g
```

This doesn't work because g is pure, so I first need to "artificially" turn it monadic. One possibility is

```
(return x) >>= f >>= (return . g)
```

which isn't very intuitive to me. Another possibility is to use that a Monad is Applicative:

```
(return g) <*> ((return x) >>= f)
```

But this is not very intuitive because of the different order of function and argument:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

What is the canonical way to deal with this? If `(>>==) = (flip ((<*>) . pure))` one can write `((pure x) >>= f) >>== g`, which would be fine except for operator precedence. Of course pure functions in monadic code are a common thing so surely there is a standard way to deal with them?

Edit: I didn't say this originally but I was thinking of a situation where I had several functions, some pure, some monadic, and I wanted to apply them in some random order.

Comment: You can use `fmap`, so `return x >>= fmap g . f`, and you can simplify that to `fmap g (f x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most straightforward solution is Kleisli composition `>=>` from `Control.Monad` module.

Since both `>=>` and `(.)` are right-associative and `(.)` has higher precedence, you can write the following:

```hs
-- (>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)

f :: Monad m => a -> m a
g :: a -> a
h :: Monad m => a -> m b
j :: b -> b

q :: Monad m => a -> m b
q  =  f >=> return . g >=> h >=> return . j
--       |         |- Use (return .) to transform (a -> b) into (a -> m b)
--       |- Use Kleisli composition >=> to compose Kleisli arrows, i.e.
--       |-   the functions going from values to monadic values, (a -> m b)
```

Comment: the functions `a -> m a` are the Kleisli *arrows*; `>=>` and `<=<` are the Kleisli (left-to-right and right-to-left) *composition* operators.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the aclaration. Didn't know ;)

Comment: The OP already rejected simply using `return . g` as "unintuitive", but I agree this is a clean approach. Something is only unintuitive until it *becomes* intuitive through repeated use :)

Comment: @chepner: yes and having the right precedence helps (which makes your answer helpful). Thanks to Ismor and WillNess. This was all very instructive!

Answer (score 11):

What you here describe is [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap). Furthermore since `pure x >>= f` should be the same as `f x`, we thus can simplify the given expression to:

```
fmap g (f x)
```

or we can make use of the infix alias [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-):

```
g <$> f x
```

Comment: Thank you! This is shortening the  `<*> . return`, right? But then what if I have several of these interwoven. Say I want to apply f then g then f then g?

Comment: @StefanWitzel: Yes. You can "chain" the functions on the left side like `(g . f . g . f) <$> x`, but perhaps I misunderstand your question?

Comment: No, I cannot (at least not this easily) because the output of f is monadic, so `g . f` does not make sense.

Comment: @StefanWitzel; ah, in that case, you an use `(g <$> f) >=> (g <$> f)` for example.

Comment: Ok now I have two problems: one is that `(g <$> f)` does not make sense, but that may go away by omitting the parentheses. The other is that my prelude does not know `>=>`.

Comment: @StefanWitzel: you can import it: `import Control.Monad((>=>))`

Comment: `(g <$> f)` is an obscure way to spell `(g . f)`.

Comment: @StefanWitzel: sorry, I made a mistake, it should be `(g <$> (f x)) >>= ((g <$>) . f)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can give your `(>>==)` operator an appropriate precedence to allow the parentheses to be dropped

```
(>>==) = flip ((<*>) . pure)
infixl 1 >>==
```

Then

```
> (>>==) = flip ((<*>) . pure); infixl 1 >>==
> pure 3 >>= (\x -> [x, x]) >>== (+1)
[4,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that I found thanks to @WillemVanOnsems pointer to Control.Monad and that is in the spirit of what I was looking for is to use `=<<` which has the same argument order as `<*>` and `<$>`:

```
g <$> (f =<< f =<< g <$> g <$> (f =<< y))
```

where now `y` is already monadic (say `return x`). The only thing I am not happy about are the parentheses due to operator precedence.

Comment: I find the type diagram [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249714/849891) helpful; you might too. also, "the four types of application" at the bottom  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118041/849891).