# Does the Applicative interface provide power beyond the ability to lift multi-argument functions (in curried form) into a Functor?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, applicative

Applicatives are often presented as a way to lift multi-argument functions
into a functor and apply functor values to it. But I wonder if there is some
subtle additional power stemming from the fact that it can do so by lifting
functions that return a function and applying the function arguments one at
a time.

Imagine instead we define an interface based on lifting functions whose argument is a tuple of arguments:

```
# from Functor
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Fa -> Fb
# from Applicative
pure :: a -> Fa

# combine multiple functor values into a functor of a tuple
tuple1 :: Fa -> F(a)
tuple2 :: Fa -> Fb -> F(a,b)
tuple3 :: Fa -> Fb -> Fc -> F(a,b,c)
(etc ...)

# lift multi-argument functions (that take a tuple as input)
ap_tuple1 :: ((a) -> b) -> F(a) -> Fb
ap_tuple2 :: ((a,b) -> c) -> F(a,b) -> Fc
ap_tuple3 :: ((a,b,c) -> d) -> F(a,b,c) -> Fd
(etc ..)
```

Assume we had the corresponding tuple function defined for every sized tuple we may encounter.
Would this interface be equally as powerful as the Applicative interface, given it allows for
lifting/applying-to multi-argument functions BUT doesn't allow for lifting/applying-to functions
that return a function? Obviously one can curry functions that take a tuple as an argument
so they can be lifted in an applicative and one can uncurry functions that return a function
in order to lift them into hypothetical implementation above. But to my mind there is a subtle
difference in power. Is there any difference? (Assuming the question even makes sense)

Comment: cf. [four types of generalized function application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118041/849891) (at the bottom of the post)

Comment: "application" is a distraction. we already can apply functions "inside" a mere *Functor*. so `mult :: Monoidal f => (f a, f b) -> f (a,b)` smashes two functorial values into one, first, and then we just apply the uncurried version of our function (`uncurry g (x,y) = g x y`) "inside" that one functorial value, by the power of Functor alone. some laws will ensure that nothing is lost by the smashing. it's the same as `x $ y == uncurry ($) (x,y)`, only "on the inside".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've rediscovered the *monoidal presentation* of `Applicative`. It looks like this:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
    (>*<) :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
    unit :: f ()
```

It's isomorphic to `Applicative` via:

```
(>*<) = liftA2 (,)
unit = pure ()

pure x = x <$ unit
f <*> x = fmap (uncurry ($)) (f >*< x)
```

By the way, your `ap_tuple` functions are all just `fmap`. The "hard" part with multiple values is combining them together. Splitting them back into pieces is "easy".

Comment: or, perhaps prettier, `(>*<) :: (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)`.

Comment: @WillNess But then you have an operator-style function that can't be called in infix notation.

Comment: ah, so, must give it  some other name then. was thinking more about the type. so `>*<` is already some kind of a comma,   alright.

Comment: Interesting! I think I prefer this view of Applicative over the one normally mentioned in articles as it focuses on the monoidal quality rather than the ability to "apply" a value to the embedded function value (which seemed obtuse when I first encountered applicatves). Similar to how the presentation of a Monad using Join instead of Bind better shows the essence of the power of a Monad above that of a Functor (i.e. the flattening of two Monad values).

Comment: *meant "seemed obscure" rather than "seemed obtuse"

Comment: @DrDR one could reasonably claim actually that Bind more immediately than Join represents the layering of the (potentially) impure and the (dependent on the previously "computed" value) pure, that is the essence of Monad.

Comment: @WillNess Good point. But I see the presence of Join as being the distinguishing feature of Monads (whereas Bind is in a sense less primitive since it can be implemented in terms the Fmap and Join)

Comment: there again, you could argue that because Join can be implemented in terms of Bind etc the opposite is true =P

Comment: @DrDR exactly. :) both ways of defining it are equally valid, but the relevance of Join is less immediately apparent, I think. after all, `fs <*> xs == join [ [f x | x <- xs] | f <- fs]` yet it's an *essentially* Applicative code, *not* [essentially Monadic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a849891%20%22essentially%20monadic%22%20%5bmonad%5d) one.

Comment: While `join` may be cleaner conceptually, `>>=` is more efficient as it fuses flattening and mapping into a single step. Put another way: `join m = m >>= id` traverses `m` once whereas `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)` traverses twice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is equally as powerful. Notice that `pure` and `tuple1` are the same. Further, everything higher than `tuple2` is recovered from `tuple2` and `fmap`:

```
tuple3 x y z = repair <$> tuple2 (tuple2 x y) z
    where repair ((a, b), c) = (a, b, c)
tuple4 w x y z = repair <$> tuple2 (tuple2 x y) (tuple2 x y)
    where repair ((a, b), (c, d)) = (a, b, c, d)
-- etc.
```

Also, all of the `ap_tuple`s are just `fmap`:

```
ap_tuple1 = fmap
ap_tuple2 = fmap
ap_tuple3 = fmap
-- ...
```

Renaming `prod = tuple2`, your question boils down to

> Is
>
> ```
> class Functor f => Applicative f where
>     pure :: a -> f a
>     prod :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
> ```
>
> equivalent to
>
> ```
> class Functor f => Applicative f where
>     pure :: a -> f a
>     liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> ```
>
> ?

And you might already see that the answer is yes. `prod` is just a specialization of `liftA2`

```
prod = liftA2 (,)
```

But `(,)` is "natural" in the sense that it doesn't "delete" anything, so you can recover `liftA2` just by destructuring the data back out:

```
liftA2 f x y = f' <$> prod x y
    where f' (a, b) = f a b
```