# Haskell - applying a function that returns a functor onto a functor

Tags: haskell, composition, functor, applicative, function-composition

Say I have function two functions `f` and `g` that both take in regular values and return an `Either` value like so:

```hs
g :: a -> Either x b
f :: b -> Either x c
```

How do I chain the two together to get something like `f . g`?

The best solution I have come up with is creating a helper function called `applyToRight` that works like this

```hs
applyToRight :: (a -> Either x b) -> Either x a -> Either x b
applyToRight f x =
  case x of
    Left a -> Left a
    Right b -> f b
```

So that I can then do

```hs
applyToRight f (g a)
```

In this case I am specifically talking about `Either`, but I think this problem could be generalized to all applicative functors. What is the most elegant way to deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not Applicative. You have rediscovered the Monadic bind:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

`Either x` is a Monad:

```
> Left "a" >>= (\x -> Right (1+x))
Left "a"

> Right 1 >>= (\x -> Right (1+x))
Right 2
```

Chaining two monad-creating functions like you have is done with the Kleisli composition operator, like `f <=< g`, or equivalently in the other direction `g >=> f` with the forward composition operator,

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

the types are easier to follow with this one:

```
      f ::               b -> Either x c
g       :: a -> Either x b
-----------------------------------------
g >=> f :: a ->               Either x c
```

In fact one way to summarize the monads is to say they are about the *generalized* *function composition*.

`>=>` is defined simply as

```
(g >=> f) x  =  g x >>= f 

(f <=< g) x  =  g x >>= f  =  f =<< g x
```

See also:

- [Monadic types diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249714/849891)
- [Generalized function application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561605/849891)
- More links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44118041/849891)

Answer (score 3):

Functor and Applicative are both too weak: Monad contains the function you seek.

```
applyToRight = flip (>>=)
```