# Bind operator for non-monadic functions

Tags: haskell, bind, monads

I more or less wrapped my head around monads, but i can't deduct how expression

```
(>>=) id (+) 3
```

evaluates to 6. It just seems the expression somehow got simplified to

```
(+) 3 3
```

but how? How is 3 applied twice? Could someone explain what is happening behind the scenes ?

Comment: The key is to realize that `(+) :: a -> m a` where `m ~ (->) a` which is a monad. (The fact that we need `Num a` for `(+)` does not change this.) Also, `id :: m a` for the same monad. So, we can have `id >>= (+) :: m a`, which is a function `a -> a` and can be applied to `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from how `>>=` is defined for the `((->) r)` types:

```
(f =<< g) x  =  f (g x) x
```

Thus

```
(>>=) id (+) 3
=
(id >>= (+)) 3
=
((+) =<< id) 3
=
(+) (id 3) 3
=
3 + 3
```

see the types:

```
> :t let (f =<< g) x = f (g x) x in (=<<)
let (f =<< g) x = f (g x) x in (=<<)
        :: (t1 -> (t2 -> t)) -> (t2 -> t1) -> (t2 -> t)

> :t (=<<)
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

The types match with

```
t1 ~ a
(t2 ->) ~ m    -- this is actually ((->) t2)`
t ~ b
```

Thus the constraint `Monad m` here means `Monad ((->) t2)`, and that defines the definition of `=<<` and `>>=` which get used.

If you want to deduce the definition from the type,

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
m ~ ((->) r)

(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
(>>=)    f            g                r =  b
  where
  a  = f r
  rb = g a
  b  = rb r
```

which after the simplification becomes the one we used above.

And if you want to understand it "with words",

```
(=<<) :: (Monad m, m ~ ((->) r)) => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
(f =<< g) x  =  f (g x) x
```

- `g` is a "monadic value" that "*can* compute" an "`a`", represented as `r -> a`
- `f a` calculates a "monadic value" that "*can* compute" a "`b`", represented as `r -> b`,
- thus `\x -> f (g x) x` is a monadic value that "*can* compute" a "`b`", given an "`r`".

**So these "non-monadic functions" are, in fact, monadic values, which happen to be functions.**

Thus in your example, `g = id`, `f = (+)`, and

- `id` is a "monadic value" that "*can* compute" an "`a`", an `a -> a`
- `(+) a` calculates a "monadic value" that "*can* compute" a "`b`", an `a -> b`, which `b` is actually also an `a`,
- thus `\x -> (+) (id x) x` is a monadic value that "*can* compute" an "`a`", given an "`a`":

```
(>>=) id (+)
=
((+) =<< id) 
=
\x -> (+) (id x) x
=
\x -> (+)     x  x
```

Comment: Not sure you need the intermediate translation to `=<<`, but perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @shree.pat18 that's the definition that I remember. :) its type `(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` also aligns nicely with the other types, of `(<$>)` and `(<*>)`, all [ending with the `m a -> m b`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561605/849891).

Comment: Thanks, great exhaustive answer, everything makes sense now. Also thanks to @shree.pat18 and chi. I would like to use the chance to ask about type abbreviations, e.g. what r in (->) r  stands for  and why isn't it t1 or a . What is the difference between t1, a, r etc... I cannot find anything on the web about it.

Comment: You might find this useful, although I too cant find an authoritative document: https://kowainik.github.io/posts/naming-conventions

Comment: they are just mnemonics of course. `r` on the right of `->` is usually for "result", here on the left of `->` I use it as a reminder of "reader" although of course the whole type is a "reader" from an "environment" so it probably should have been `e` instead (but `e` is also often an "error" as in e.g. `Either e a`). `a`, `t`, etc are for the more generic types.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some colour to Will's excellent answer.

If we look at the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%3E%3E%3D), we have this:

> ```
> instance Monad ((->) r) where
>        f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
> ```

If we rearrange the input expression slightly, we get  `(id >>= (+)) 3`. This now resembles the form shown above. Now fitting the input into the above 'template', we can rewrite the input as `\ r -> (+) (id r) r`

This is the same expression we arrived at for the final evaluation i.e. `(+) (id 3) 3`